# Equivalent md5 hash for PHP and vb.NET 2008

Tags: php, hash, md5

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim source As String = TextBox1.Text
    Using md5Hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()
        Dim hash As String = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, source)
        TextBox2.Text = hash
    End Using
End Sub
```

I've used the above code generate a md5 of 32 characters. The md5 for "1234567" is given as 
   **fcea920f7412b5da7be0cf42b8c93759** but I want the md5 hash to be generated as         **d38f0d62daf542c5f10d8f29adacae17** as it is generated by md5() function of PHP.

How do I generate equivalent md5 hash in VB.NET?

Comment: Why do you think it should be d38f0d62daf542c5f10d8f29adacae17 ? Also, perhaps you should show the code for your `GetMd5Hash` function. Note that since MD5 works on byte input, the text encoding you use, matters.

Comment: I know d38f0d62daf542c5f10d8f29adacae17 means "1234567" because I've created that using a plugin for Counter Strike 1.6. 

Shared Function GetMd5Hash(ByVal md5Hash As MD5, ByVal input As String) As String
        Dim data As Byte() = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
        Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
            sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
        Next i
        Return sBuilder.ToString()
    End Function

Comment: And how does the CS plugin calculate it ? How is the string "1234567" converted to bytes ?

Comment: I've added few amx plugins which calculate the md5 itself. I don't know the algorithm :D

Comment: Then you need to know the salt to get the same value in VB ...

Comment: well, I know the value of salt I used, so how do I use it in vb?

Comment: #define salt d38f0d62daf542c5f10d8f29adacae17
> 
> 
The above line is coded in the plugin.

Comment: Let's say the salt is "salt", and you appended it to the data in CS. Then you need to do the same in VB: Append it to the input before calculatiing the md5.

Comment: You do realise that your salt is the same value as you claim is the MD5 of the data, right. I believe you might have an error in you plugin.

Comment: I tried appending, I succeeded to get hash of 32 characters, but not the same hash. Please help! :)

Comment: A little bit of demonstration about how I use the salt in vb to generate same hash?

Comment: out of interest, what is the md5 being used for? (I'll point out that md5 is not secure -- even with a salt it's not considered a secure way of protecting a password. there are other uses for it which are still fine, but if you're using a salt it implies you are trying to use it for security purposes; if that's the case, I'd recommend using a more secure hashing algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding is the problem. Encoding that you are using in VB.NET to generate hash is different from what is used by PHP. You must use the same encoding that the PHP uses while generating the hash from VB.NET. It could be like:

```
Dim BytesArray() As Byte
BytesArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your Input String)
```